# Why does the distance at apogee and perigee of the moon change?

Tags: orbital-motion

I'm a  student who's trying to analyze some data for the distance between the earth and the moon (specifically, to model with sinusoidal functions in our math class.)  In my research, I gathered some data, and I saw the expected changes in Earth-Moon distance (due to the elliptical orbit).   However, I also saw that the distance at apogee and perigee changes as well:

[image: Distance at apogee and perigee looks like a sinusoidal function, not constant]

Why is this?  I saw [another question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/168857/why-isnt-the-time-between-apogee-and-perigee-constant) which asked why the time *between* apogee and perigee varied, and it was due to the effects of the sun.  **Edit:** Looks like I misunderstood this, sorry.  Could this phenomenon be because of the same reason as in the linked question?

CY

Comment: Are we assuming the y-axis in your plot is measuring from Earth center to Moon center?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure the data is from the Earth center to the Moon center.